# Restrict access to update sharepoint list via infopath

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, sharepoint-list

Not sure if this is possible or not, hoping someone has encountered, and resolved a similar issue. 
Data for my sharepoint list is gathered, and updated via an infopath form which i created.
I would like to restrict access to certain fields after the form is initially submitted. i.e. 
user initially provides the following info

- mame
- age
- address
- occupation.

After the initial submission, i would like the user to be able to go into the list item and edit the "address" and "occupation" details, but i want all other fields to be locked.

Hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what if they have a birthday!?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field, such as "submit status", and give it a default value of "not submitted". Then, in your submit button rules, add a rule to set that field to a value of "submitted". This way, you'll know if the form is being viewed for the first time or not. Then, either set up a second view with a rule on the form open event that changes views based on the value of that field, or a set up rules to conditionally disable individual textboxes/controls based on the value of that field.